# What is the meaning of "Gomel" as used in the term "Gemillat Chessed"?

Tags: words, chesed-kindness

Other than its use in Tehillim / Tefilla, the only place I can think of where the verb גמל is used (I'm not referring to a camel) is in the phrase גמילות חסדים, or similar forms of this phrase (singular form, etc.)

What is the translation of גמל as used, here? I don't think it means just "giving" as then, why not use the verb מתן or similar? Why is the word גמל used with this mitzvah? I don't see it used with some other mitzvah.

Comment: Where is it used in Psalms? What does it mean there? Does the meaning there fit the usage in "gemillut hassadim"? || _as then, why not use the verb מתן or similar_ Why is one synonym more appropriate than another?  || _I don't see it used with some other mitzvah._ Which other mitsvah do you think should have it? Note that gemillut hassadim probably isnt an actual mitsvah anyway. Its just an expression for certain kind acts.

Comment: It *is* used in other places also - see for instance Br 50:17, "כִּי רָעָה גְמָלוּךָ"

Comment: Or Sam. I 24:17 "כי אתה גמלתני הטובה ואני גמלתיך הרעה"; an act of doing/performing.

Comment: @Rish Hah! In this week's parsha of all places. I have to check that. Thanks.

Comment: Guys... Is Tanach no longer considered on-topic in a site about Judaism? Leave this thing open please.

Comment: If you want to understand פשט in words you have to be familiar with using a קנקורדנציא -- here is a link for this word in an online version: http://mg.alhatorah.org/Concordance/1580

Comment: @DonielF You dont seem to have read the question. The question is not about Tanakh. It is about the definition of a Hebrew term in an expression, assuming specifically that it is NOT following its usage in Tanakh.

Comment: @mevaqesh גמילות חסדים is a phrase found in at least as far back as Peah 1:1, so if it doesn’t count for Tanach it should count for understanding the meaning of how Chazal describe a mitzvah

Comment: @DonielF OK. If you are going to state an objection, state the correct one, before asking sarcastic questions about others' voting. Also consider editing the source for the term into the post, which would strengthen it, providing more reason for it to be about Judaism, rather than merely about some Hebrew term.

Comment: @mevaqesh I had been under the mistaken impression the term was actually in Tanach.

Comment: @DonielF Don't worry. There is no shame in admitting mistakes. And you can just delete comments that contain them. Note, however, Yeshaya 63:7 and Mishlei 11:17.

Comment: Note further ברוך הגומל לחייבים טובות שגמלני כל טוב.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Jastrow, גמילות in the expression גמילות חסד is a noun, not a verb. The singular of the noun is גמול or גמולא which means *deed, reward or recompense*.

It is worth noting that Jastrow says it is Aramaic. The Hebrew form is גמל. And the Hebrew form as a noun is associated with both the camel (the one who carries the physical load) and the camel driver (the one driving the animal/camel, the Nefesh HaBehamit). So in context, it would have a meaning of an *executor*, one who *executes* the action.

Another interesting point from Jastrow concerning the usage as it refers to the camel driver, is that the camel driver leads his animal (walks in front of it), in contrast to an ass driver (חמר), who follows behind the animal.

The verb form in Hebrew also appears in Bereshit 21:8 and according to the Targum has a connotation of *finishing* or *completing*. This would mean that **Gemilut Chesed** is bringing Kindness from *potential* into an actual, *finished* state.

Comment: גמילות is also Mishnaic Hebrew. Are you sure Jastrow isn't saying it's Aramaic just because his book is an Aramaic dictionary?

Comment: As far as I am aware, Jastrow doesn't originate anything. If he brings something, it is from an earlier source. It is possible that this particular idea is from the Aruch. (the dictionary by that name)